# Implementing a singly LinkedList and IList interface

Tags: c#, linked-list, generics, collections

I have implemented a `LinkedList` in C#. What would you change/make better? What naming conventions are misused? What would you add? Some of my ideas are to make it thread-safe.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestIt.DataStructures
{
    public class MyLinkedList<T> : IList<T>
    {
        private int size;
        private MyLinkedListNode<T> head;

        public long Size()
        {
            return size;
        }

        public void Add(T nodeValue)
        {
            Add(new MyLinkedListNode<T>(nodeValue));
        }

        public void Add(MyLinkedListNode<T> newItem)
        {
            if (size == 0)
            {
                head = newItem;
            }
            else
            {
                var last = head;
                while (last.Next != null) { last = last.Next; }
                last.Next = newItem;
                newItem.Prev = last;
            }
            size++;
        }

        public MyLinkedListNode<T> Get(long index)
        {
            if (index > size)
            {
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException(String.Format("List size is {0} but the index {1}", size, index));
            }
            long c = 0;
            var curr = head;
            while (c != index) { curr = curr.Next; c++; }
            return curr;
        }

        public bool Remove(long index)
        {
            if (index > size)
            {
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException(String.Format("List size is {0} but the index {1}", size, index));
            }

            if (size == 0) return false;

            long c = 0;
            var curr = head;
            while (curr.Next != null && c < index) { curr = curr.Next; c++; }

            if (curr.Prev == null && curr.Next == null)
            {
                curr = null;
                head = null;
            }
            else if (curr.Prev == null) { curr.Next.Prev = null; head = curr.Next; curr = null; }
            else if (curr.Next == null) { curr.Prev.Next = null; curr = null; }
            else
            {
                curr.Prev.Next = curr.Next;
                curr.Next.Prev = curr.Prev;
                curr = null;
            }
            size--;
            return true;
        }

        public bool Remove(MyLinkedListNode<T> node)
        {
            if (size == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            var curr = head;
            while (curr != null && curr != node) { curr = curr.Next; }
            if (curr == null) { return false; }
            curr.Next.Prev = curr.Prev;
            curr.Prev.Next = curr.Next;
            curr = null;
            size--;
            return true;
        }

        public int IndexOf(T item)
        {
            if (item == null)
            {
                return -1;
            }

            int index = 0;
            var curr = head;
            while (curr != null)
            {
                if (curr.Value.Equals(item))
                {
                    return index;
                }
                curr = curr.Next;
                index++;
            }
            return -1;
        }

        public void Insert(int index, T item)
        {
            if (index > size + 1)
            {
                throw new Exception("Index if out of range of the linked list");
            }

            var curr = head;
            var i = 0;
            if (index == i)
            {
                var newNode = new MyLinkedListNode<T>(item);
                newNode.Next = curr;
                head = newNode;
                size++;
                return;
            }
            curr = curr.Next;
            i++;

            while (curr != null)
            {
                if (i == index)
                {
                    var newNode = new MyLinkedListNode<T>(item);
                    newNode.Next = curr.Next;
                    curr.Next = newNode;
                    size++;
                    return;
                }
                curr = curr.Next;
                i++;
            }
        }

        public void RemoveAt(int index)
        {
            Remove(index);
        }

        public T this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                if (size < index - 1)
                {
                    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
                }

                var curr = head;
                int i = 0;
                while (curr != null)
                {
                    if (i == index)
                    {
                        return curr.Value;
                    }
                    curr = curr.Next;
                    i++;
                }
                return default(T);
            }
            set
            {
                if (size < index - 1)
                {
                    var curr = head;
                    int i = 0;
                    while (curr != null)
                    {
                        if (i == index)
                        {
                            curr.Value = value;
                            return;
                        }
                        curr = curr.Next;
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            size = 0;
            head = null;
        }

        public bool Contains(T item)
        {
            if (size == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            var curr = head;
            while (curr != null)
            {
                if (curr.Value.Equals(item))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                curr = curr.Next;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
        {
            if (size == 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            var curr = head;
            while (curr != null)
            {
                array[arrayIndex] = curr.Value;
                curr = curr.Next;
                arrayIndex++;
            }
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get { return (int)size; }
        }

        public bool IsReadOnly
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public bool Remove(T item)
        {
            return Remove(new MyLinkedListNode<T>(item));
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            var curr = head;
            while (curr != null)
            {
                yield return curr.Value;
                curr = curr.Next;
            }
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }

    public class MyLinkedListNode<T> : IComparable<T>
    {
        public T Value { get; set; }

        public MyLinkedListNode<T> Next { get; set; }
        public MyLinkedListNode<T> Prev { get; set; }

        public MyLinkedListNode(T value)
        {
            this.Value = value;
        }


        public int CompareTo(T other)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Possible problems**

- `MyLinkedListNode<T> Get(long index)` passing negative index will lead to a `NullReferenceException` but should lead to an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.
- Calling `CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)` with `array == null` will lead to an `IndexOutOfRangeException` but should lead to an `ArgumentNullException`.
- Calling `CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)` with `arrayIndex >= array.Length` will lead to an `IndexOutOfRangeException` but should lead to an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.
- The guard condition in the `this` getter should be changed from

  > ```
  >     if (size < index - 1)
  >     {
  >         throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
  >     }
  > ```

  to  this

  ```
  if (size-1 < index)
  {
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
  }
  ```

  otherwise with `size == 1` calling with `index == 1` or `index == 2` would succeed.
- You should change every guard condition which states

  > ```
  > if (index > size)
  > ```

  to

  ```
  if (index >= size)
  ```
- `Insert(int index, T item)`

  here you need to change the guard condition also and you should throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` instead of a `System.Exception`.

**Nitpicking**

> ```
> public int Count
> {
>     get { return (int)size; }
> }
> ```

The cast isn't necessary.

**Update** based on comment

> ```
> public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
> {
>     if (size == 0)
>     {
>         return;
>     }
>     var curr = head;
>     while (curr != null)
>     {
>         array[arrayIndex] = curr.Value;
>         curr = curr.Next;
>         arrayIndex++;
>     }
> }
> ```

In the way you have coded the `CopyTo()` method, you are using the `arrayIndex` as the indexer of the passed in `T[] array`. This is differenet than the [`Array.CopyTo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06x742cw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) implementation of the NET framework.

In the NET implementation `arrayIndex` would be the starting index of the source array. For the NET `CopyTo()` the `arrayIndex` needs to be `< sourcearray.Length`. If you had the intention that your method behaves like the `Array.CopyTo()` method you would need to rewrite it like

```
public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
{
    if (size == 0 || arrayIndex >= size)
    {
        return;
    }

    var current = Get(arrayIndex);

    int destinationCounter = 0;
    int arrayLength = array.Length;

    while (current!= null && destinationCounter < arrayLength)
    {
        array[destinationCounter] = current.Value;
        current= current.Next;
        destinationCounter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for response. Re-consider your third point: `arrayIndex >= array.Length`. Would you agree that `if(arrayIndex + Count >= array.Length)` should throw `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` instead of `arrayIndex >= array.Length`?

Comment: No, I won't agree. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

- You could make `MyLinkedListNode` private nested class of `MyLinedList`. It is implementation detail, so it shouldn't be visible to the end user. Making it nested you also hide it from other top-level classes of your module (assembly). Invisible things can't be broken.
- You could also create two or three private helper methods. F.e. `Remove(int)`, `Insert(int, T)`, `this[int]` all are implements the loop to find i-th element. Do not repeat yourself, avoid duplicate the code. It simplify both testing and maintain of the code.

You can make the code more uniform. These two statements looks completely different:

```
if (size == 0)
{
    return false;
}
```

and

```
while (curr != null && curr != node) { curr = curr.Next; }
```

Uniform code easier to read.

Otherwise, it's good code: readable, understandable.

Comment: He certainly *could*. Buy why *should* he? Your answer would be much better if you included some justification for your recommendations.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko, thanks for your input. Don't you think users (I mean class users) should be able to create instance of `MyLinkedListNode`? - This is the reason of leaving the node class public instead of nested private.

Comment: It seems that none of public methods has parameters or return values of type `MyLinkedListNode`. It just means that users doesn't need this type.

Comment: `public bool Add(MyLinkedListNode<T> node)
public bool Remove(MyLinkedListNode<T> node)` These two have... Do you think it's better to change the arguments just to T?

Comment: You can declare any method as a `public`, but disclose details of the implementation considered VERY BAD IDEA. As a rule, it's enough to open methods of `IList<T>` only. Since `IList<T>` has `Add(T)` and `Remove(T)` you should implement them anyway. `Add(MyLinkedListNode<T>)` may be useful to simplify the implementation, so you can make it `private` and call from your other methods only.

Answer (score 0):

I would make Size a read-only property, rather than a method that returns a backing field. This requires some small refactoring, but the main change is removing the `int size` and changing the `Size()` method to a read-only property:

```
public long Size { get; private set; }
```

In your `Add()` method, instead of walking the list, you could just use the `Get()` method to grab the last node. This reduces some code duplication.

```
public void Add(MyLinkedListNode<T> newItem)
{
    if (Size == 0)
    {
        head = newItem;
    }
    else
    {
        var last = Get(Size - 1);
        last.Next = newItem;
        newItem.Prev = last;
    }

    Size++;
}
```

In your `Get` method, you should probably not allow negative numbers. You also need to change your comparison between `index` and `Size` to be `if (index >= Size)`. Also, a small nit-pick, I would use a `for` rather than a `while`, since your condition and counting variable is defined, checked, and incremented in one place.

```
public MyLinkedListNode<T> Get(long index)
{
    if (index < 0) throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Index cannot be negative");

    if (index >= Size)
        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException(
            String.Format("List Size is {0} but the index {1}", Size, index));    

    var curr = head;

    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
        curr = curr.Next;
    }

    return curr;
}
```

You might also consider adding another private `Remove` function that does the legwork of repointing the Prev and Next properties to reduce code duplication. Note I'm also calling `Clearr()` if both `Prev` and `Next` are null, since this can only be the head in that case:

```
private void RemoveNode(MyLinkedListNode<T> node)
{
    if (node == null) return;
    if (node.Prev == null && node.Next == null) 
    { 
        Clear();
        return;
    }
    if (node.Prev != null) node.Prev.Next = node.Next;
    if (node.Next != null) node.Next.Prev = node.Prev;
    Size--;
}
```

Also, in your `Remove()` method, you need to change your comparison between `index` and `Size` to be `if (index >= Size)`. You could also simplify the code by using your `Get()` method. I don't see how this can fail, so I'm returning void:

```
public void Remove(long index)
{
    if (index < 0) throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Index cannot be negative");
    if (index >= Size)
        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException(
            String.Format("List Size is {0} but the index {1}", Size, index));       

    var itemToRemove = Get(index);

    RemoveNode(itemToRemove);
}
```

Now in your other Remove function we can again take advantage of our private `RemoveNode` method. You can also simplify the code by using a `for` loop which will initialize, validate, and increment your nodes in one place. Also, this one could fail (without throwing) if the node doesn't exist, so it returns a bool:

```
public bool Remove(MyLinkedListNode<T> node)
{
    var foundNode = false;

    for (var curr = head; curr != null; curr = curr.Next)
    {
        if (curr == node)
        {
            foundNode = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (foundNode) RemoveNode(node);

    return foundNode;
}
```

For `IndexOf` the only change I would make is to use a `for` loop because I think it looks cleaner:

```
public int IndexOf(T item)
{
    if (item == null) return -1;

    int index = 0;
    for (var curr = head; curr != null; curr = curr.Next)
    {
        if (curr.Value.Equals(item))
        {
            return index;
        }

        index++;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

For the `Insert` method, you should check for a negative `index`. Also, I would allow someone to specify `Size` as an index (which is one more than the last index), and just call the `Add()` method in that case. Otherwise, the code can be simplified greatly by using the `Get()` method:

```
public void Insert(int index, T item)
{
    if (index > Size || index < 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("Index if out of range of the linked list");
    }

    var itemToInsert = new MyLinkedListNode<T>(item);

    // Inserting at the end is the same as Adding...
    if (index == Size)
    {
        Add(itemToInsert);
        return;
    }

    var existingNodeAtIndex = Get(index);
    itemToInsert.Prev = existingNodeAtIndex.Prev;
    itemToInsert.Next = existingNodeAtIndex;
    existingNodeAtIndex.Prev = itemToInsert;
}
```

Next, I think the index check in your `this` implementation needs to be changed. After that, I don't see why you couldn't just call your `Get()` methods here? The error handling in those methods should do, I think.

```
public T this[int index]
{
    get
    {
        return Get(index).Value;
    }
    set
    {
        Get(index).Value = value;
    }
}
```

Finally, your `Contains()` method can use the already implemented `IndexOf()` method:

```
public bool Contains(T item)
{
    return IndexOf(item) >= 0;
}
```

Comment: Just finished some edits, should be done now!